# Select IF EXISTS as a BIT column

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, join

I have a query that currently looks like this:

```
 SELECT
     d.Region_Name
    , d.Dealer_Name
    , RIGHT(r.Vin,8) AS VIN
FROM 
    tblCCDealerCall_Customer c
    JOIN tblCCDealerCall d ON c.DealerID = d.DealerID
    JOIN tblReservation_TestDrive r ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Simple enough.But, now I want to add a fourth column called IsVinActive, which is a BIT.  I need to check in another table, tblVinDisabledDate, to see if the current VIN exists in that table.

I can use this query to see if a VIN exists in that table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM tblVinDisabledDate vd WHERE vd.Vin = '2LMPJ6LP5GBL54709'
)
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

But I'm not sure of the best way to integrate that into the first query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Try this.

```
SELECT
     d.Region_Name
    , d.Dealer_Name
    , RIGHT(r.Vin,8) AS VIN
    , CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblVinDisabledDate WHERE Vin = r.Vin)
      THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
FROM tblCCDealerCall_Customer c
JOIN tblCCDealerCall d ON c.DealerID = d.DealerID
JOIN tblReservation_TestDrive r ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

If you want to avoid a correlated query, `join` the other table as well.

```
SELECT
      d.Region_Name
    , d.Dealer_Name
    , RIGHT(r.Vin,8) AS VIN
    , CASE WHEN vd.vin is not null then CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END 
FROM tblCCDealerCall_Customer c
JOIN tblCCDealerCall d ON c.DealerID = d.DealerID
JOIN tblReservation_TestDrive r ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN tblVinDisabledDate vd ON vd.Vin = r.Vin
```

Comment: Ok -- it's really that simple?  I've been told to avoid inner SELECT statements when building a column at all costs.  Was wondering if there was a more elegant, less expensive way.

Comment: Why use a case with exists instead of wrapping the subselect in an isnull?
CONVERT(BIT,ISNULL(SELECT 1 FROM ....),0))

Comment: Tips: You could wrap the `CASE` in a single `CAST` rather than casting each value. I often use `declare @True as Bit = 1, @False as Bit = 0;` in stored procedures and then use those variables in queries to make the intent clear and remove the need for casts.

Answer (score 1):

```
;With cte
as
(
SELECT
     d.Region_Name
    , d.Dealer_Name
    , RIGHT(r.Vin,8) AS VIN
FROM 
    tblCCDealerCall_Customer c
    JOIN tblCCDealerCall d ON c.DealerID = d.DealerID
    JOIN tblReservation_TestDrive r ON r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
)
select * ,case when b.vin is null then 0 else 1 end as 'somecol 
from cte c
outer apply
(select 1  as vin from tblVinDisabledDate vd where vd.vin=c.vin) b
```